# Can $\sum_{κ=0}^n \sin^3 (θ_2 + κdθ)$ be turned into a Riemann sum?

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

While trying to find the magnetic field over a solenoid I ended up with two answers that through desmos look to be approximately the same:
$$\frac{1}{α}\sum_{κ=0}^n \sin^3 (θ_2 + κdθ)$$
where $α$ the radius of the solenoid, $dθ = \frac {θ_1 - θ_2} {n}$
and,
$$n(\cosθ_2 - \cosθ_1)$$

Is there a way to "pull" $dθ$ out of the function and get to the definition of the Riemann integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$f(x)=\sin^3\big(\theta_2+x(\theta_1-\theta_2)\big).$$
Then
$$\frac1n\sum_{\kappa=0}^n \sin^3(\theta_2+\kappa d\theta)=\frac1n\sum_{\kappa=0}^n f\left(\frac\kappa n\right),$$
which equals
$$\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$$
in the limit as $n\to\infty$. As a result,
$$\frac1\alpha\sum_{\kappa=0}^n \sin^3(\theta_2+\kappa d\theta)\approx \frac n\alpha \int_0^1 \sin^3(\theta_2+x(\theta_1-\theta_2))\,dx.$$
You can calculate this integral as
$$\int_0^1 \sin^3(\theta_2+x(\theta_1-\theta_2))\,dx=\frac{9(\cos\theta_1-\cos\theta_2)-(\cos(3\theta_1)-\cos(3\theta_2))}{12(\theta_1-\theta_2)}.$$
As far as I can tell this doesn't align exactly with what you've written, but it might be numerically close to $n(\cos\theta_2-\cos\theta_1)$ for the values of $\theta_1,\theta_2,\alpha$ you're using (or it might simplify for those values).

Comment: Turns out $\frac{1}{a} = \frac{-3 \pi}{4}$ and they turn out exactly equal for the problem. (which constraints $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$). Peculiar.